# Проблема перевода byte[] в String[] или в String. JAVA

Tags: java, строки, charset, bytearray

Я посылаю запрос на сервер, он мне отправляет `String[]` или `String` с помощью `byte[]`. Моя задача - преобразовать этот массив байтов хоть в что-нибудь читаемое. Пока, что получаю каракули. Пробовал делать через `new String(bytes, charset)`, `new String(bytes)`, `Arrays.toString(bytes)`, но результата нет. Насколько я знаю, с сервера данные приходят в кодировке 1251.

Comment: Мало информации. По идее `new String(bytes, Charset.forName("cp1251"))` должно работать. Кинь кусок своего кода. Можно еще и поток данных обернуть в ридер с нужной кодировкой и читать не байты, а сразу строки.

Comment: Вот этим методом я читаю байты:
public byte[] receiveBytes() {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        try {
                in.read(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }return bytes;
    }
А вот этим превращаю их в String:
public static String bytesToString(byte[] bytes, Charset charset) { return new String(bytes, charset); }

Попробовал кодировку "cp1251", все равно каракули.
Еще попробовал перебрать все доступные кодировки, в паре из них относительно все нормально, то есть данные есть, но присутствует пару каракуль.

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы преобразовать массив байт в строку нужно знать в какой кодировке они записаны. А потом вызвать конструктор `String` с указанием нужной кодировки

```
Charset ch = Charset.forName("windows-1251");
byte[] data = {(byte)0xCF, (byte)0xF0, (byte)0xE8, (byte)0xE2, (byte)0xE5, (byte)0xF2};
String str = new String(data, ch);
System.out.println(str);
```

> Привет